# Mongo Db: How to use $set and $in in the same query

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7

lis=['http://www.example.com/','http://www.example2.com']

lis1 = [410,403]

I need to update the above list in mongoDB. Below is my query

> posts1.update({'$and':[{'website_url':{'$in':ll}},{'status':0}]},{'$set':{'status_code':{'$in':ll1},'status':2}},multi=True)

But I come across the error stating,

**pymongo.errors.WriteError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$in' in 'status_code.$in' is not valid for storage.**

Kindly help me to modify the query.

Comment: As you note, it's an error. In fact a MongoDB error. So you don't supply the `$in` at all, but rather "loop" the array entries with [`.bulk_write()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write)

Comment: Oh. But I have a doubt. when I executed the $and part, where website_url has $in, it worked perfectly. only when I added the $in in $set this error popped out.

Comment: A "query" is perfectly fine and is meant to work. An "update" is another story, since `$in` is analogous to `$or` and can "possibly" match more than one given position in a matched document. That's another error that you would see. Your specific usage "here" is not valid as an argument to `$set` because MongoDB thinks you are assigning to a "property" named `$in`, and thus errors how you have seen.

Comment: The linked question is your "intent" to update "multiple documents" that match the given `$in` condition and then update for each value. So what the solution there tells you is "don't do that". Instead loop the array items to construct the statement.

Comment: Oh. Thanks a lot for the explanation @Neil Lunn.